# How to move connected walls together while moving a single wall in GOJS-Floorplanner

Tags: gojs

I am using GOJS Floorplanner typescript version. Wanted to know how can we go about moving connected walls together. I am able to move a wall and then extend the connected walls but not dynamically. Movement is happening after doMouseUp of the selected wall is called

Answer (score 0):

Use `dragsTree: true`

Gets or sets whether moving or copying a node also includes all of the node's tree children and their descendants, along with the links to those additional nodes.

https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/DraggingTool.html#dragsTree

```
  myDiagram = GoJs(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv", {
            .....
            "draggingTool.isEnabled": true, // enable undo & redo
            "draggingTool.dragsTree": true, // Drag node along with all child nodes 
            .....
        });
```

Comment: Doing that will help in moving the wall parts such as door and windows but for connected wall to be dragged,one wall gets moved will the connected once are streched or resized.So this wont work.Thanks